# Dynamic status indicator in pysimplegui app

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to add a status indicator functionality to a small PySimpleGUI app I'm making. When the event "Connect" is executed without error, I'd like to set the indicator to green and if "Disconnect" is executed, the indicator should be set to red. Is it possible?[App preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJgI1.png)

```
if event == "Connect":
    print("IP address", inputIP)
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(connecttotv.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = process.communicate()
    except:
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update("Something went wrong")

if event == "Disconnect":
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(disconnecttotv.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = process.communicate()
    except:
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update("Something went wrong")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lot of ways for indicator, one example here is the color of `sg.Text`.

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

status = [('\u2B24'+' Disconnect', 'red'), ('\u2B24'+' Connect', 'green')]
state = 0

layout = [
    [sg.Text(text=status[state][0], text_color=status[state][1], size=(20, 1),
        justification='center', font=("Courier New", 24), key='INDICATOR')],
    [sg.Column([[sg.Button('Connect'), sg.Button('Disconnect')]], justification='center')],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Exit"):
        break
    elif event == 'Connect':
        state = 1
    elif event == 'Disconnect':
        state = 0
    if event in ('Disconnect', 'Connect'):
        value, text_color = status[state]
        window['INDICATOR'].update(value=value, text_color=text_color)

window.close()
```